# include another loopback project

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I am trying to setup a project workflow in [loopback](http://loopback.io/) which utilizes 2 different projects which include a base project.

Here is what I want to do:

```
loopback-project-1
|__loopback-project-2
|__loopback-project-3
```

So the idea would be to have all my basic tasks like authentication and authorization in `loopback-project-1` and then include that in `loopback-project-2` and `loopback-project-3` to save me from re-creating that logic in the other projects. In other words, I need some way to share models across multiple loopback applications without having to duplicate code.

I tried creating a bootscript to try to load the other application as express middleware but that only seems to expose the REST API; NOT the models.

Here is my bootscript:

```
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/base', require('../../../loopback-project-1/server/server'));

    boot(app, '../../../loopback-project-1/server/server', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
};
```

**Note: This bootscript would be included in `loopback-project-2` and `loopback-project-3`.**

My end goal is to be able to use loopback as the primary development stack for a multi-application architecture with a heavy focus on code re-use. The idea would be to include `loopback-project-1` into other projects which would automatically include base models as well as any base functionality which resides in `loopback-project-1`; such as authentication / authorization.

Let me know how this can be accomplished.

Thanks